# Iterate through a list in the widget tree with an index

Tags: flutter, dart

Im currently able to iterate through a list within the widget list using a `for` loop as follows:

```
                            for (var value in myList)
                              MyWidget(
                                  data: value,
                              ),
```

But is it possible to iterate through a list and maintain an index to know which item in the list we are currently on?

Comment: `for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) ...` but it is not handy if you have to use `myList[i]` in multiple places

Comment: i would rather use `myList.mapIndexed(...).toList()`

Comment: how about **List.generate(myList.length, (index) => MyWidget(data: myList[index]))**

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your `List` into a `Map` and loop on its `entries`:

```dart
void main() {
  final list = ['a','b', 'c', 'd'];
  list.asMap().entries.forEach((item) => print('${item.key}: ${item.value}'));
}
```

#### Console log

```
0: a
1: b
2: c
3: d
```

In a Widget tree, it would be something like:

```dart
return Column(
  children: list.asMap().entries.map((item) => Text(
    '${item.key}: ${item.value}',
  )).toList(),
)
```

Comment: there is [mapIndexed](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-collection_collection/IterableExtension/mapIndexed.html) for such case: `list.mapIndexed((index, item) => ...)`